# How to return query result to a tset and later process the data?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, functions

Table and values are as follows:

```
-- create a table
CREATE TABLE table (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  a integer[],
  b integer[]
);
-- insert some values
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, '{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}', '{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}');
```

I try to write a function, which has a query that returns a result set - several records of the table. I wrote something using cursor before, which fetch one row in each loop. But I thought it might not be necessary to fetch row by row, but all rows in once.

The following was the script I wrote now, where the result is put into a two-dimensional array, but I don't know how to iterate rows for further processing. Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function1(IN x integer[], IN y integer[])
returns integer[][]
AS $$
declare
    row integer[][];

    index integer;
    i integer;
    j integer;
    v integer;
    d_id integer := 0;
begin
    select * from table where id = any(x) into row;
    
    loop
    

    #processing data 

    end loop;
    return count_values;

end; $$ 
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: I doubt you need a 2-dimensional array. So far it's not yet clear what's supposed to go into the result exactly. And always disclose your version of Postgres.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter You are right, it actually not a two dimensional array. It's a set of records of the table. Can I somehow put it in a parameter, and later get them by something like parameter.id, parameter.x, parameter.y?